# trying to read every number in a text file python

Tags: python, file

basically this is the  file :

```
15
5
20
4
36
6
81
9
12
2
20
5
```

what I'm trying to do is to print every number by pair so for example :
a= 15
and b=5

```
15 5
```

now
a =20
and b =4

```
20 4
```

it goes on until it printed all the numbers  (its part of another function)
i had 2 attempts at this :

```
f=open("fraction.txt","r")
    l=len(f.readlines())
    f.close()
    f=open("fraction.txt","r")
    for i in range (l) :
        if not f.readline()== "" :
            a=int(f.readline())
            b=int(f.readline())
            print(a,b)
```

the output is :

```
5 20
36 6
9 12
20 5
None
```

so it skips the first number which is 15 for some reason and the last output is none
this is my second attempt

```
f=open("fraction.txt","r")
    l=len(f.readlines())
    f.close()
    f=open("fraction.txt","r")
    for i in range (l) :
        a=int(f.readline())
        b=int(f.readline())
        print(a,b)
```

output :

```
15 5
20 4
36 6
81 9
12 2
20 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\amine\Desktop\pyyyy\smiGod.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(fraction("fraction.txt"))
  File "c:\Users\amine\Desktop\pyyyy\smiGod.py", line 8, in fraction
    a=int(f.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
PS C:\Users\amine\Desktop\pyyyy>
```

so what's the problem here ?

Comment: It skips a line because your `if` statement is consuming a line.

Comment: in my second attempt why does it print none at the end ?

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`: You have a blank line at the end of your file. A blank string can't be converted to an integer. Check if the string is black before trying to convert it

Comment: how can i remove it

Comment: Since you haven't shown us all the code, we can't explain the "None".  Based on the traceback, you have called `print(fraction("fraction.txt"))`, but the function doesn't return anything.  Hence, it prints `None`.

Comment: i see so thats why i thought because the line was empty

Answer (score 0):

Don't use lengths if you don't have to.

```
f=open("fraction.txt","r")
save = None
for line in f:
    if save is not None:
        print( save, int(line) )
        save = None
    else:
        save = int(line)
```

Comment: can you tell me what"s wrong with my method im just trying to understand better here

Comment: What's wrong is that you are opening and reading the complete contents of the file twice.  That's utterly wasteful.